# Convert working Ruby on Rails form to AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a working Ruby on Rails form that currently posts my results and redirects the user to another view and posts the results.  The flow is:

```
views/tools/index.html.erb -> views/tools/ping.html.erb
```

Since I have it working now, I'd like to convert it to AJAX and keep the user on the `views/tools/index.html.erb` view, getting rid of the redirect to enhance the user experience.  However, I'm unsure of how to proceed based on the way that my `Tools` controller is currently setup, and my incredibly lacking knowledge of AJAX.

So, here's what I currently have:

**views/tools/index.html.erb (added 'remote: true' to form)**

```html
<h1> Tools </h1>

<h3> Ping </h3>

<%= form_tag ping_tool_path(1), method: "post", remote: true do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :ip, params[:ip] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Ping", name: nil %>
<% end %>

<!-- this is where I'd like to put the results via AJAX -->
<div id="output"></div>
```

**controllers/tools_controller.rb**

```html
class ToolsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    
  end

  def ping
    ping_host(params[:ip])
    save_host(params[:ip])

    # Adds based on recommendations
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to tools_path }
     format.js
    end
  end


  protected

    def ping_host(host)
      f = IO.popen("ping -c 3 #{host}")
      @output = f.readlines

      tool_type = "ping"
      tool = Tool.find_by(tool_type: tool_type)
      tool.increment(:tool_hit_count, by = 1)
      tool.save

      @results = "<pre>#{@output.join}</pre>".html_safe
    end

    def save_host(host)
      host = Host.find_or_create_by(host_ip: host)
      host.increment(:host_hitcount, by = 1)
      host.save
    end
end
```

**views/tools/ping.html.erb**

```html
<%= @results %>
```

**views/tools/ping.js.erb (New file based on suggestion)**

```html
$("#output").html("<%= @results %>");
```

**routes.rb**

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'tools#index'

  resources :tools do
    member do
      post 'ping'
    end
  end
end
```

**This is what I see on the Network tab in Google Chrome after submitting the form:**
[image: Network Tab of Google Chrome]

So, what I know at this point is that **I'll need to add `remote: true`** to my form in `views/tools/index.html.erb`, and this is where I get lost.

It seems that I have an issue ATM with the fact that I've abstracted the form to use my `ping` method in the `Tools` controller, whereas all of the tutorials (and railscasts) I've gone through are doing AJAX on CRUD methods and a given model, not something like what I've build here so far.  **Please help me understand AJAX!**

Comment: What happens when you do <%= form_tag ping_tool_path(1), method: "post", remote: true do %>

Comment: @MattW. From the backend, both my `tool_hit_count` and `host_hitcount` are updated, however, my view stays on `index.html.erb`.  So, from the UI perspective, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, now you need to modify the `def ping` action with a `respond_to` block.

```
def ping
  ping_host(params[:ip])
  save_host(params[:ip])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to tools_path } ## if you still want to have html
    format.js
  end
end
```

and create a file called `view/tools/ping.js.erb` where you have javascript that will be run and returned asynchronously

```
$("#output").html("<%= j @results %>");
```

The <%= %> block will be evaluated first and replaced with the output of that ruby code. Then this will be inserted into the #output div.

Comment: Well, at least I wasn't far off!  Ok, I made the change, I see that in console log that `Rendered tools/ping.js.erb (0.6ms)` did happen, however nothing is displayed in the `<div id="output"></div>` area yet.

Comment: @Godzilla74 if you're on Google Chrome you can open up the inspect element -> then click the Network tab, it should show you what is being called on the network and what response is being sent back.

Comment: @Godzilla74 my response does require you to have jQuery. That could be it.

Comment: I added a screenshot of what the Network Tab shows after the form submit.  I don't see a reference to the `ping`

Comment: I do have the `jquery-rails` gem installed

Comment: @Godzilla74 the remote:true call should show up on that page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96738/discussion-between-john-and-godzilla74).